# Photoshop Black Workspace\Pointer Error

Tags: adobe-photoshop, osx-yosemite

Running OS X 10.10 & Photoshop CC 2015 Legit license on official Apple Unibody MacBook hardware. Nothing is pirated or on a hackintosh.

Problem occurred after both OS X & Adobe Creative Cloud updated. My entire work area (everything between rulers & scroll bars) is black. I know it's not just the canvas bounds. As I have zoomed out to the point the image should be nearly invisible & everything is still black. The color picker tool & swatches panel also falter.

[image: Photoshop Screenshot]

Tried each Drawing Mode setting, disabling use of graphics card, multiple memory usage allowances, moving the cache/scratch to SSD, tried each image mode setting & bit depth. Also manually did a system wide driver(kext) update. No difference has been made, doesn't matter what settings are used.

After trying everything else I can think of I uninstalled all 3rd party utilities & drivers. Slowly introducing them back into the system. I believe the problem is linked with the driver for [my tablet](http://goo.gl/NuIBuE).

Uninstalling the driver resolves the graphics issue, reinstalling restores. So great right, just uninstall the driver & use Apple's stock tablet driver. Unfortunately I lose use of the shortcut keys on the tablet edge, pressure sensitivity settings & proper multi-display support. Though the stock driver for OS X may work. It's not as functional as the official Monoprice driver which used to work in Photoshop & still does in all other software.

What I would like to know is how common a problem this is. I've found some scattered information around the internet about mouse/pointer drivers causing black screen issues. Mostly for Windows/Direct X & not OS X mind you. At any rate none of the "fixes" mentioned work for my tablet & setup.

For the time being I've contacted Monoprice & gone back to stock Apple driver for Photoshop & reinstall when texturing inside of Blender. I would greatly appreciate if anyone had any insight they could share.

If there is simply nothing left to do. Are there any recommendations for a different tablet? One that is known to work still.

**~** *Edit* **~** 
**Summary:**
The issue is **not display specific**.
**OpenGL settings do not** have any **affect**.
**Drawing Mode settings do not** have any **affect**.
**Memory Usage settings do not** have any **affect**.
**Image Mode & Bit Depth settings do not** have any **affect**.
There is **no flickering**, **workspace is solid black**.
**All drivers** are now **most recent versions**.
There was **no issue present prior to** both Adobe CC & OS X system (*not OS version*) **update**.
[**f.lux**](https://justgetflux.com/) has also been determined **not** to be **the cause**.
**Removing** the secondary and/or tertiary **displays does not resolve** the issue.
**Only known solution is uninstalling [tablet](http://goo.gl/NuIBuE) driver**.
A **bug report** has been **submitted to Monoprice**.

Comment: To preempt the question. Yes I have tried turning it off & on again.

Comment: Have you tried removing Photoshop preference file from ~/Library/Preferences/ ? It did work for me once. make sure you keep a copy of them just in case it doesn't work for you

Comment: Thanks, that actually indirectly solved a different issue I had. Though the black workspace is still present if driver is installed. This is indeed quite a perplexing problem.

Comment: Try with & without OpenGL switched on - see if one may be better. Preferences/Performance - uncheck or check Use Graphics Processor & relaunch.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the suggestion. However that was the first thing I tried, second mentioned in OP. The only noticeable difference was sluggish mouse response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with the most recent update from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a different tablet. This may seem a little odd. But try moving the Photoshop window to a different display. The black workspace issue is present when using the built-in display and at least 1 external.

Comment: This has no effect for me. The only cause I can find is with the tablet driver. Thank you though.

Comment: That sounds very much like an openGL issue, @Thoric - quite often graphics cards don't fully support OGL on the secondary monitor port